# mailgun throws error in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailgun

if I require mailgun I get an error that says

```
function promisifyCall(ctx, fn, ...args) {

SyntaxError: unexpected token ...
```

that comes from the npm module promisify-call 
anyone know why?

Comment: What version of node are you using? This looks like an issue where the version of node doesn't support the es6 syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like your node version doesn't support modern js (**es6** & above). I suggest you update your node version to **6.x**.

Another good idea would be to install **nvm** (https://github.com/creationix/nvm) which allows you to easily swap the node version via your command line.

If you don't want to update your node version:

Without knowing the node version you're using, you may be able to use the following v8 flags in your start script

```
--harmony --harmony_destructuring 
// Example:
node --harmony --harmony_destructuring index.js
```